# How to debug php code in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I want know, how to debug php code in eclipse.

I have added required files for register form.

And i referred some answers from stackoverflow, i took a look through http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf thislink. but i just i confused.

Now i have done like this:

[image]

Can you help me, how to debug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: out of theme: i suggess you this debugger http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: i am asking with eclipse

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but some of the related steps are described in [this blog](http://maruhgar.blogspot.com/2014/06/setting-up-and-running-php-unit-tests_26.html)

Comment: You may also want to give some more details - which version of eclipse, php, apache (if relevant) and operating system

Comment: @ghost: are you there?

Comment: @user4119973 sorry man can't help you with this one, usually i just use xdebug for debugging purposes

Comment: it's ok @ghost. but i just confused